# Jquery selection not working on multiple line link

Tags: jquery, css

I have paragraphs that are links, and I would like my Jquery behavior to trigger when it is over the entire paragraph. The HTML is, which comes from [this page](http://newsite.paulwagenblast.com/?s=visual):

```
<ul id="search-results">
  <li>
    <a href="http://newsite.paulwagenblast.com/loveadorned/">Love Adorned ... Branding and identity development for concept lifestyle shop. Over two years, directly managed full cycle of <span class="search-excerpt">visual</span> identity and brand development of luxury lifestyle boutique from inception of retail...</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want a cursor to be an X anytime the cursor is not over the li or a of this HTML. I have tried jQuery selecting anything that is not li, not #searchresults li, but when the cursor moves between the text of the link, it turns back to the X. I would like that when the cursor moves anywhere over the li, it is the hand link cursor. My jQuery is here:

```
jQuery("body").hover( 

    function(a) {
    if ( jQuery(a.target).is(':not("#searchresults li")' ))
       {
            // Anywhere on the page that is not #searchresults li turn to the X cursor:
            jQuery("body").css("cursor", "url(http://paulwagenblast.com/newsite/wp-content/themes/blankslate/assets/PWDS_WEB_X.png) 25 25, pointer");   
       }

        }, function() {
            // Anywhere on the page that is #searchresults li, be the regular cursor
           jQuery("body").css("cursor", "default");

        }

    );
```

Can you recommend a better way to select this, so that when the mouse moves over the li a linked paragraphs, the cursor does not turn back to the big X?

Comment: why don't you put this in your css styles?

Comment: So when you hover over the lis you want a cursor?

Comment: @LioraHaydont you were right; putting this in my CSS was easiest. I made it so:
`
#searchresults li {
 list-style: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
`
and in header-search.php I just wrote an inline style so that the cursor anywhere on the body was an X:
`
<body <?php body_class();?> style="height:100vh; cursor:url(http://paulwagenblast.com/newsite/wp-content/themes/blankslate/assets/PWDS_WEB_X.png) 25 25, pointer;" 
`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if ( jQuery(a.target).is(':not("#searchresults li")' ))
```

To This:

```
//Add the link(s) inside the li as well to the condition so the cursor doesn't change to an X
if ( jQuery(a.target).is(':not("#searchresults li")' && jQuery(a.target).is(':not("#searchresults li a")') ))
```

Comment: when I tried:
`if ( jQuery(a.target).is(':not("#searchresults li")' || jQuery(a.target).is(':not("#searchresults li a")') ))`
which was in your comment first, and then changed the operator to AND, it worked both ways, but it disabled the X over the rest of the body. I haven't figured out why yet. For now it has been simplest to just change the CSS. Thanks for your help though.